# Drawing a text with source light effect

Tags: inkscape, perspective

I have a very basic experience with Inkscape and I am trying to make something like this

[image]

I tried to use Shadows and shear to change the text orientation but cannot get anything closer
.
Could you please guide me on how to achieve that result? I appreciate your help

Comment: You may well ask the author of this image, who has recently [posted it on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/hvpbsc/inkscape_is_love_inkscape_is_life/) together with several other great drawings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way to do this in Inkscape is to **skew** your text and add a **perspective effect** to a **blurred copy** of the text itself.

Start with your text:

[image: Original text]

Using the handles, you can **[skew](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html)** it to give a perspective tense:

[image: Text skewed]

Now, **duplicate** the text by hitting <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> and draw a rectangle of the same size of the bounding box of the text, [snapping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html) to the text:

[image: Rectangle]

Convert the Rectangle [to path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html), hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and move the nodes of the rectangle in the desired position of the shadow:

[image: Rectangle as a shape of the shadow]

Select one of the text, convert to a path and add the [Path effect](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Perspective.2FEnvelope) **Perspective/envelope**. Please note that once converted to a path the text cannot be edit (*I should have written "its" and not "his" ... oops!*).

[image]

Hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, **move the nodes of the envelope** to fit the shape of the rectangle:

[image: Add perspective to the text]

Now the rectangle is useless, you can delete it or move it to a hidden layer. Please note that you didn't need the rectangle to add the path effect, it was just for explanations purposes:

[image: The text with the perspective]

Now, lower the text to be used as a shadow, give a slight [blur](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Fill-Stroke.html) and opacity to its fill:

[image: Blur and opacity to the shadow]

Add a background and change the fill of the text:

[image: Final text]

Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any way to add variable blur, so the blur radius increases as the distance from the source increases? (To emulate reality more accurately)

Comment: Perhaps you can fill the shadow with a linear gradient (not tried).

Comment: See also [here](https://www.deviantart.com/hrum/art/inkscape-blure-46507939) and  [here](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic5435.html?t=5628), and also consider to subdivide the shadow and apply different blur levels.

Comment: Very nice answer. Can you see, if you have a bit of your time, my questions? :-) Best regards.